# cxf restful service return 404 error when using "@QueryParam"

Tags: java, spring, rest, cxf

I want to query information from the server using restful query parameters in url. The java code retrieves query parameter using @QueryParam.

My request url is like this:

```
GET
http://localhost:8080/ApacheCXF-XML-JSON-IO/services/playerservice/query?id=238
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
accept:application/json
```

The interface is:

```
@Path("/playerservice")
public interface IPlayerService {
    // http://localhost:8080/ApacheCXF-XML-JSON-IO/services/playerservice/getplayer/238
    @GET
    @Path("getplayer/{id}")
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED})
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public PlayerType getPlayerInfo(@PathParam("id") int playerId);

    // http://localhost:8080/ApacheCXF-XML-JSON-IO/services/playerservice/query?id=238
    @GET
    @Path("query")
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED})
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public PlayerType queryPlayerInfo(@QueryParam("id") int id);
}
```

The implementation of interface is :

```
@Service("playerService")
public class PlayerServiceImpl implements IPlayerService {
    /**
     * retrieves a player object based on the playerId supplied in the formal argument using @PathParam
     */
    @Override
    public PlayerType getPlayerInfo(int playerId) {

        // retrieve player based on the id supplied in the formal argument
        PlayerType getplayer = new PlayerType   ();
        getplayer.setPlayerId(playerId);
        getplayer.setName("Allan Donald");
        getplayer.setAge(47);
        getplayer.setMatches(72);
        return getplayer;
    }

    @Override
    public PlayerType queryPlayerInfo(int playerId) {
        // retrieve player based on the id supplied in the formal argument
        PlayerType getplayer = new PlayerType   ();
        getplayer.setPlayerId(playerId);
        getplayer.setName("Allan Donald");
        getplayer.setAge(47);
        getplayer.setMatches(72);
        return getplayer;
    }
}
```

After starting tomcat, I use postman to test the restful service. I send the get request as above, but the server returns a http 404 error as follows:

```
    十一月 16, 2017 8:41:41 下午 org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.WebApplicationExceptionMapper toResponse
警告: javax.ws.rs.ClientErrorException: HTTP 404 Not Found
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.SpecExceptions.toHttpException(SpecExceptions.java:117)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.ExceptionUtils.toHttpException(ExceptionUtils.java:167)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.findTargetMethod(JAXRSUtils.java:536)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.processRequest(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:177)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.handleMessage(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:77)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:267)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:191)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:301)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doGet(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:225)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:276)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: what is the request url u r sending from postman?

Comment: You're also missing the first few lines of your interface.  please share.

Comment: @pvpkiran The url sending from postman has been already posted above. It is :    _italic_     http://localhost:8080/ApacheCXF-XML-JSON-IO/services/playerservice/query?id=238

Comment: @JohnAment I have completed the missing header of interface.

Comment: I have found the root cause. Query method is added later. The project is not built because of a library error. So the tomcat always uses the old project files. It could not find query method of cause.